# Exclude weekends and custom days (i.e. Holidays) from date calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Currently, I am calculating a finish date based on the start date (DateTime) and duration (# of days), but my calculations do not take into account weekends or holidays.

So, my solution is not correct. This was just a starting point.

I read some articles out there and one approach is to create a gigantic calendar table that has all the weekends and holidays for the next 50 years. I guess the idea is to query a date range against the calendar table and subtract the # of weekends and/or holidays.

The problem is the software I am working on allows users to set their own project calendar.
Wouldn't the table become to large to maintain given that the software allows users to manage multiple projects?

So, I guess my question how do I get started and what are some possible approaches to this problem?

Basically, for each project task I need to calculate the task finish date given the START date and DURATION, but taking weekends and custom days(aka holidays) into consideration.

Any ideas?

BTW: I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Which RDBMS? (SQL Server? Oracle?)

Comment: 50 days?  Could that be a typo?  Most calendar tables should have data for years.

Comment: Just edited from days to years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read some articles out there and one approach is to create a gigantic calendar table that has all the weekends and holidays for the next 50 years. I guess the idea is to query a date range against the calendar table and subtract the # of weekends and/or holidays.

It's because some holidays don't consistently fall on the same date.  Labour day for example - the first Monday of September.  It's easier & takes less space in the db to store the date it falls on in a per year basis than to try to code the rules to calculate it.

Other considerations are holidays that land on Sat/Sun - it's a tossup if the day off will fall on Monday or Friday.  And some holidays will be federal while others are local...

Comment: D'oh... didn't get my answer in until after this one had been accepted.

Comment: Easter isn't too bad, because you can find a formula for it. The bigger problem is when there are extra days thrown in, like when the UK had an extra public holiday for the Jubliee in 2002, or Australia had an extra public holiday for the start of the Sydney Olympics in 2000. For this, you really need a table listing the days off, or have a "IsHoliday" field in a calendar table.

Comment: Or consider things like Ramadan, which varies from year to year and from place to place. It's also *decreed*, not caclulated (though the date of decree can be estimated by calculations). http://j.mp/GKzaM

Answer (score 1):

Create a large calendar that contains all weekends and holidays for the rest of the [long period of time], have it set to select only.  Then copy the needed days into the calendar into the project's calendar each time a new project is created.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a table called AllDays, which has columns called theDay and IsPublicHoliday. Also suppose your @@DATEFIRST is set to 1, so that your weekends are days 1 and 7. You want to find the date which is @n days on from @StartDate.

```
WITH NumberedDays AS
(
SELECT theDay, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY theDay) AS DayNum
FROM AllDays
WHERE DATEPART(dw, theDay) NOT IN (1,7)
AND IsPublicHoliday = 0
AND theDay > @StartDate
)
SELECT theDay
FROM NumberedDays
WHERE DayNum = @n
;
```

If you don't have a table called AllDays, then you can easily use a table of numbers, where theDay is DATEADD(day,num,@StartDate). You could do a LEFT JOIN to your list of ineligible days (which should be indexed, of course).

Answer (score 0):

@Stuart: Yes, 50 days is a type =P. I meant 50 years.

@rexem:
That's true. The calculations would be too complex and error-prone.

@David: Creating a select-only master calendar table and then copying the dates I need per project sounds like a great idea.

(pardon, my twitter-like response, haha)

Thanks for the great responses!

Comment: You need some rep so you can leave comments :p

Comment: My apologies. I do see the comment button now. I wasn't fully aware of the distinction. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is haw I resolve it:

first I created a calendar table (tb_cal) with two fields date_day (smalldate), holiday (bit)

```
CREATE TABLE [user].[tb_cal](
[date_day] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[holiday] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

then this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [user].[fc_get_labor_days]
(@from datetime, @to datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
return ( 
select count(*) as total 
from tb_cal 
where datepart(dw, date_day) not in (1,7)   
and holiday <> 1 
and date_day > @from and date_day <= @to )
END
```

you can call this function by passing the parameter (from, to)

```
SELECT user.fc_get_labor_days(my_date_from, my_date_to) as [days]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get next wrking date after excluding weekends and Holidays

```
Declare @AddDay as integer = 3
Declare @NextWorkingDate  DateTime
Declare @StartDate  DateTime = Cast(getdate() as date)

While  @AddDay > 0 
    begin

        Select @NextWorkingDate =  @StartDate + @AddDay +
        (datediff(wk, @StartDate, @StartDate+ @AddDay  ) * 2) -- add weekend 

        --Exclude weekend
        If datepart(dw,@NextWorkingDate ) = 1 or datepart(dw,@NextWorkingDate ) = 7  --Add 2 days if target date is either Saturday or Sunday
            set @NextWorkingDate = @NextWorkingDate + 2 

        --Count no of holidays if falling within start date and nextwrking date
        Select @AddDay = Count(*)  from HolidayTable ST --Holiday list
                    where ST.OffDate between @StartDate+1 and @NextWorkingDate
        Set @StartDate = @NextWorkingDate
    End         

Select @NextWorkingDate
```